# How to build uniapp component library with vite and vue3?

Tags: uniapp

How to build uniapp component library with vite and vue3?

When imported vite and vue3 component library

the uniapp `npm run dev:mp-weixin`cannot work in mp which send error:

[image]

how to make my vite and vue3 compnent library work in uniapp for wechat

my vite config is

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: "./lib/main.ts",
      name: "vue-ui",
      fileName: "lib",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```